# Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar not found on Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Sorry maybe this is not new topic, but really need help, i was try many post about this, but my problem still not fix, i am newbie about android. I try to learn Material Design, i use android lollipop, API level 22.

i try to use `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'`. After sync the gradle, i still not able to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as my theme on `style.xml` file. This is my completely gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "afnan.project.com.materialdesign"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
 dependencies { 
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

is there another settings so i can try to use this theme, or what is the main problem? pls tell me, Need advice..

Answer (score 6):

Theme `Theme.AppCompat.*` is used to define compatibility with old android 2.x versions. this requires the `support-v7`

If you need compatibility with android 2.2 or 2.3 include this in your gradle build

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:22.0.0'
```

or if you build is for android-3.0 or later replace `AppCompat` with `Holo`.

Example

- Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

becomes

- Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: Thanks for your great information @k3b, it's basic question, is material design can created from all kind of parent theme, for example, `android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`? And with resource which i have, can i use it to start to learn material design? Sorry still learn..

Comment: i have no knowledge about material design

Answer (score 3):

Previously it was

`<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

now

`<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: it worked for me <3 Mine was flutter project

Answer (score 0):

To use the **AppCompat** Theme you have to include this library in your project.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Also I suggest you using the latest version 22.2.0 instead of 22.0.0

```
dependencies { 
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

     //You can remove this line, because the appcompat has the support-v4 as dependency
     //com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio  Right click on Gradle and right click of mouse button Refresh Gradle project issues is resolved .