# app crash when switching activity from item menu

Tags: android, android-activity

This is the code:

SudokuMain.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.action_newGame:
            ((SudokuBoardView) findViewById(R.id.vsudoku_board)).newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_test:
            Intent intent = new Intent(SudokuMain.this, PrimoRisultato.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            finish();
         /*   if (LinkMatrix.Test()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Test Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Test Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SudokuMain"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrimoRisultato"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
```

when i click on button to switch activity the app crash.
I saw several guide / codes but it doesn't works.

Ok so I think the problem is that in SudokiMain i use a theme with actionbar but in PrimoRisultato i use a theme without actionbar.
This is the stack trace (red text):

```
08-18 14:41:27.602    7471-7471/com.example.face_offbrains E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.face_offbrains, PID: 7471
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.face_offbrains/com.example.face_offbrains.PrimoRisultato}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Is there a way to resolve " You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity " without actionbar?

Even put Theme.AppCompact like this the app crash.

```
<activity
        android:name=".PrimoRisultato"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeActionBar">
    </activity>
```

and menu.xlm

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_newGame"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_newGame"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_test"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_test"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: We can't know without you posting your stack trace, but my guess would be that you didn't declare `PrimoRisultato.class` as an activity in your manifest.

Comment: I didn't post in manifest the declare of PrimoRisultato

Comment: Where is stack trace?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401771/theme-appcompat-light-noactionbar-not-found-on-android-studio/31402188#31402188

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need pass activity result use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SudokuMain.this, PrimoRisultato.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```