# How to programatically create material design EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

When programmatically creating an EditText via it's constructors EditText (Context context), it creates one with the old android designs :

[image]

**It does not allow for text selection**, (but I am able to move the cursor). How do I make an EditText with the newer designs, like so :

[image]

I already found how to remove the orange border (i.e. with setBackgroundColor) but I can't find a way how to change the cursor design and **how to make possible to select text** (ie i mean to see the left and right text select handle). I need to do all of this programmatically because I create the EditText on the fly in Delphi (so no xml).

---

As requested this is the `AndroidManifest.xml` that goes with my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.myapp.app"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="myapp" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">



        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="myapp"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="myapp" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Comment: Most of the time style of the widgets is inherited from theme in application tag in AndroidManifest. Can you post the AndroidManifest.xml file as well?

Comment: So you want custom cursor like black cursor, green cursor If I am not wrong

Comment: @jakubbialkowski i just post the content of my AndroidManifest.xml. But it's not only design, right now i can't even select text in my edittext :(

Comment: @Bhavnik yes custom cursor, but also to be able to select some text in my Edit text because right now i can just move the cursor but not select any text :(

Comment: @loki can you verify result of following theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: @jakubbialkowski sure but i don't know how to do this ?

Comment: Just change this line in your AndroidManifest.xml android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" to android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" and be sure that you have in build.gradle added support library like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31402188/4985575

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is create an EditText XML in your layout folder that you can reuse, and you can specify the style in that.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="SUPPLY YOUR STYLE HERE FROM STYLES.XML" />
```

You can also tell it to use a theme. Then, you inflate it like this:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.SOME_LAYOUT, null);
```

To make your text selectable, you can try this:

`editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);`

Comment: thanks VicVu, but how it's will work if right now i can't even select any text (i can see only the middle text handle selector, but not the left or the right text handle selector)? also i would like to avoid to use any XML

Comment: thanks vicVU for your support, but unfortunatly the setTextIsSelectable didn't help, i still not be able to see the right and left text select handle :( i can see only the middle text select handle ..

Answer (score 0):

[Screen shot of text selection is here](http://prntscr.com/cfhnvp) Hey loki,
try this one, it might be helpful to you.....
In java file enter below snippet

```
try {
        Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(editEmail, R.drawable.cursor_black); // set your programmatically generated edittext in this method
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**create cursor_black.xml in your drawable folder.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<size android:width="2px" />
<solid android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

And also try to extend AppCompatActivity in your activity class

Answer (score -1):

Use the 3 parameter version of the constructor and pass in the style you want.

Comment: but i can't understand how to use it EditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) ... do you have some sample ? what to put in AttributeSet and defStyleAttr ?

Comment: Attribute set it's the set of attribute values,  basically all the android: stuff from xml. The third parameter is the style